# Input elements right next to each other, covering whole container width

Tags: html, css

Not the most self explanatory title I've ever authored.

What I'm trying to do (**[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlowgren/ddYmH/)**) is for the text field and button to remain positioned *right* next to eachother  (no margins), with the button to the right, and thetext field covering 100% of the remaining width of the container that the button isn't occupying. The relationship between the two should remain even if the containing element is resized.

Browser requirements: IE9+, Firefox, Webkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/ddYmH/19/). The code is pretty-self explaining, but here's the basic idea:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "cell">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Glee's awesome!" />
    </div>
    <div class = "cell" style = "width: 1px"> <!--make sure it's only large enough to fit the button-->
        <button type="submit">Glee</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;   
}
```

Hope that helped!